# VBA: Using Dims in a Vlookup

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm trying to do a vlookup in VBA and I'm getting an `Application-defined or object-defined error` run-time error.

I rewrote the line with integers and strings instead of `Dims` and it works fine, but I need to make it variable.

```
'Throws Error
rc = -6
tempwb = "Supplier Master - Location - 08-13-15.xls"
acol = 1
zcol = 14
wRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[rc],'[" & tempwb & "]Sheet1'!C" & acol & ":C" & zcol & "," & ((zcol - acol) + 1) & ",FALSE)"


'Works
wRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=Vlookup(RC[-6],'[Supplier Master - Location - 08-13-15.xls]Sheet1'!C1:C14,14,FALSE)"
```

Comment: `"=VLOOKUP(RC[" & rc & "],...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try changing

```
wRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[rc],
```

to be

```
wRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[" & rc & "],
```

Done?

Comment: Oh my god... Thank you.  I'm upset that I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

It was easy enough to diagnose by doing this:

```
Dim sFormula As String

sFormula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[rc],'[" & tempwb & "]Sheet1'!C" & acol & ":C" & zcol & "," & ((zcol - acol) + 1) & ",FALSE)"

Debug.Print sFormula

wRange.FormulaR1C1 = sFormula
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your string so you include the rc variable.

```
wRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[" &rc&"],'["
```